# ERROR : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4

Tags: java, arrays, oop

Can anyone please point out the mistake, the error its showing is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
at com.company.Grid.pushZero(Grid.java:42)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:14)
My Code is

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Random;
public class Grid {
    Random rand = new Random();


    int newnumber() {
        double rand1 = rand.nextDouble();
        if (rand1 < 0.2) {
            return 4;
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    }


    int[][] array = {{0, 0, 0, newnumber()}, {0, 0, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}};

    void display() {


        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; ++j) {

                System.out.print(array[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    void pushZero(int[][] array, int n) {


        int count1 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (array[i][j] != 1) {
                    array[count1++][j] = array[i][j];
                    while (count1 < n) {
                        array[count1++][j] = 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    while (count1 < n)
                        array[count1++][j] = 1;
                }
                int lastNonOne = 0;
                for (int a = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (array[a][j] == 1)
                        continue;
                    if (lastNonOne == 0) {
                        lastNonOne = a;
                    }
                    if (array[i][j] !=0)
                        array[lastNonOne--][j] = array[i][j];
                }
                while (lastNonOne >= 0)
                    array[lastNonOne--][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to reset `count1`. Or, rather, you've mis-scoped it. It shuold probably be declared 2 nest-levels deeper, right above `if (array[i][j]...`) - the first loop, count1 is upped to `4` (or rather, upped to whatever `n` is, but I assume that pushZero is called with `n=4`), and then next loop, it just carries on where it left off, trying `array[4]`, in effect, and that causes an AIOOBEx exactly as you get it - there is no `array[4]`, there's only `array[0]` through `array[3]`.

Comment: Hi I still cant find the mistake can you please fix it for me?

Comment: If it's homework, I would be hurting your future career if I do that. If this is not  homework, I'm signing you up for running to SO every 10 minutes, and I'd be hurting SO and your future career if I do that. So, no. You're welcome.